# iOS graphic resolution sizes

Tags: ios

I have read countless reference sites but cannot find a simple answer.

I wish to have a bmp graphic on the screen and willing to have multiple versions so as to satisfy all screen sizes and resolutions. What sizes do I put into;
iPhone 1x, 2x, Retina 4 2x 3x?
iPad 1x, 2x?

If anyone refers me to this site http://www.iosres.com/ it seems to be of no help to me as graphics still appear as the incorrect size, often oversized, sometimes bordered.

Comment: I would recommend to visit this site for getting a clear picture about resolutions and devices instead: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Answer (score 1):

Heres a nice handy reference for IOS screen resolution sizes.

You can get a high res PDF copy at the link below

http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

[image: IOS resolution guide]